# Closed form expression of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \exp[-\alpha(x^2-a^2)^2]$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

Is the following integral $$I(a,\alpha)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \exp[-\alpha(x^2-a^2)^2]$$ analytically solvable i.e., have a closed form expression? Here, $\alpha, a$ are real positive constants. I'm not being able to reduce it to standard improper integrals.

If such a closed form expression for $I(a,\alpha)$ does not exist, what can we say about the limiting values of the integral as $\alpha\rightarrow 0^+$ and $\alpha\rightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: Why do you have the $dx $ before the function? Is it on purpose?

Comment: @RSerrao It's just one of those notation things

Comment: @RSerrao It doesn't matter.

Comment: where can i find $$\lambda$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner typo corrected. thanks.

Comment: i think there is no elementary antiderivative

Comment: Bessel functions will do the job here

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Be%5E(-b%5E2(y%5E2-a%5E2)%5E2),%7By,0,inf%7D,Assumptions-%3E%7Ba%3E0,b%3E0%7D%5D

Comment: The choice of $a$ and $\alpha$ as names of the involved parameters makes the integral quite difficult to parse. Additionally, one parameter between $a$ and $\alpha$ is pretty useless, since it can be removed by a suitable substitution.

Comment: After using parity and rescaling, split the range of integration at $1$. sub $x=\cos(y)$ in the first and $x=\cosh(y)$ in the second of the resulting integrals. Massage the resulting expression into something which can be written in terms of http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.4 and you are done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we define
$$ I(a,b) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-b(x^2-a^2)^2\right]\,dx $$
for $a,b>0$, by setting $c=ba^4$ and $x=az$ we get:
$$ I(a,b) = a \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-c(z^2-1)^2\right]\,dz = a\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-c(z-1)^2\right]\,\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} a\,J(c)$$
and:
$$ J(c) = \int_{-1}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-c z^2)}{\sqrt{z+1}}\,dz =\color{blue}{\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{\exp(-cz^2)}{\sqrt{z+1}}\,dz}+\color{red}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-cz^2)}{\sqrt{z+1}}\,dz}$$
where the blue integral can be approximated by expanding the integrand function as a Taylor series and the red integral can be studied by switching to Laplace transforms and getting values of Bessel functions. In any case, the behaviour depends on the magnitude of $\color{green}{ba^4}$.

In terms of [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html),
$$ I(a,b) = \frac{\pi a}{2 \exp(ba^4/2)}\left[I_{-1/4}(ba^4/2)+I_{1/4}(ba^4/2)\right].$$
It follows that if $ba^4$ is large we have
$$ I(a,b) \approx \frac{\pi a }{\sqrt{\pi b a^4}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b a^2}}$$
while if $ba^4$ is close to zero we have 
$$ I(a,b) \approx \frac{\pi}{2^{3/4}\Gamma(3/4)b^{1/4}}.$$

Comment: i think that the complete integral should be expressible in a sum of modified besselfunctions of the first kind, so no approximation is needed here (but i'm too lazy for doing all the algebra at the moment)

Comment: @tired: as usual, you are right, but since the OP seemed interested only in asymptotics, I thought it was enough to outline an approach to get them. Essentially, we just have to compute an approximation for the the Laplace transform at $c$ of a function having the form $\frac{1}{z^\alpha (1+z)^\beta}$.